# How do i apply Data Augmentation on entire data-set

Tags: python, data-augmentation

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uYYVY.png)

Hello Guys, I am new to Machine Learning and trying to learn it. I tried data augmentation on my data-set. i got this code from keras website but this code is just picking 1 image at a time. I want this code to pick image one by one from the data-set and apply augmentation techniques on it. I am confused on what to change in it. I will be very thankful if someone helps me.

```
from keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator, array_to_img, img_to_array, load_img

datagen = ImageDataGenerator(

        rotation_range=40,
        width_shift_range=0.2,
        height_shift_range=0.2,
        shear_range=0.2,
        zoom_range=0.2,
        horizontal_flip=True,
        fill_mode='nearest')

img = load_img('data/train/cats/cat.0.jpg')  # this is a PIL image

x = img_to_array(img)  # this is a Numpy array with shape (3, 150, 150)

x = x.reshape((1,) + x.shape)  # this is a Numpy array with shape (1, 3, 150, 150)

i = 0

for batch in datagen.flow(x, batch_size=1,
                          save_to_dir='preview', save_prefix='cat', save_format='jpeg'):

    i += 1

    if i > 20:

        break  # otherwise the generator would loop indefinitely
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am assuming you have the dataset in your `data/train/cats/` folder. Now, given the above code, it reads a single image, runs augmentation on that single image, and produces 20 different images.

Now, to extend the process, you can simply use the `os` or `glob` module to get the list of files from the directory. And then loop over the block of your code. For example:

```
import glob

list_of_files = glob.glob('data/train/cats/*.jpg')
for file in list_of_files:
  img = load_img(file)  # this is a PIL image
  x = img_to_array(img)  # this is a Numpy array with shape (3, 150, 150)
  .
  .
  .
```

Rather than looping over the whole block of your code, you can utilize the `datagen.flow` more, i.e. instead of passing a single image as `x` , you can pass the whole dataset. For example, if `n` is the total number of images, your `x` shape will look like `(n,3,150,150)` assuming all images are the same size.

Also, you can vary this `n` value. i.e. not choosing the total dataset length. In that case, say `n` value is `20`, at first iteration, you will read first `20` images and pass `x` like `(20,3,150,150)`. Then at second iteration, you read the next `20` and so on.

For example,

```
import glob
import numpy as np

x = []
list_of_files = glob.glob('data/train/cats/*.jpg')
for file in list_of_files:
  img = load_img(file)  # this is a PIL image
  x.append(img_to_array(img))
x = np.array(x) # feed this x to your datagen.flow

# print(x.shape)
# (n, 3, 150, 150)

# (Note: n is the length of list_of_files, i.e. total dataset length)
```

Comment: Thank You Sir its working. Sir, as i am new to python and machine learning i don't get it how i send whole number of images as "n". can you please tell me by changing in the above code so i can understand i will be very thankful to you.

Comment: You can simply append the images in a list and then convert to a numpy array. I have added an example.

Comment: Hello Sir, Hope you doing fine. Sorry for disturbing you again. Sir the code you send i tried but i am only get 11 images from it. Sir the shape of image is: (504, 200, 200, 3).

Comment: ` x.append(img_to_array(img))
x = np.array(x) # feed this x to your datagen.flow

print(x.shape)



i = 0
for batch in datagen.flow(x, batch_size=1,
                              save_to_dir=r'C:\Users\Munib\Desktop\Augmented', save_prefix='ws12', save_format='jpeg'):
        i += 1
        if i > 10:
            break  `

Comment: Okay. In the above scenario, your ````batch_size```` and max ````i```` value determines the number of images that will be generated. So, if you want to increase the number of generated images, you will need to increase either one of the parameters. In the first approach, you fixed a single image and based on that single image, you try to generate variations. On the latter approach, you randomly pool an image from your ````(504, 200, 200, 3)```` and generate the variations.